# what does do method class in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

This might be a silly question. I'm learning objective C  (iOS) by studying the code and I came across the expression

```
[InstanceName class];
```

What does it do?

I tried to search for class method but It just pops up difference between class method and instance method etc. I guess it might give some sort of class object but I have no idea what is the purpose of the statement.

the original code is Sample Facebook App (scrumptious) using FB SDK....

Comment: It might be easier to read some documentation before trying to decipher the code... Just saying.

Comment: @CaptJak  The documentation doesn't really help in this case unless you dive very deep into the runtime and linker docs.

Comment: @bbum: True. But I was also referring to the: "I'm learning objective C (iOS) by studying the code". I wasn't bashing him for asking the question. The question is fine.

Comment: @CaptJak I'm certainly going through documentation. This is a sample app for tutorial and this line was quietly ignored in description. I was just interested, that's all, no need to kick in the open door.

Comment: What's going on??? Now I feel bad! I am not saying you are doing anything wrong, just throwing in another option, which wasn't mentioned. Sorry if I offended. I get it, you were down voted... Wasn't me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see something like this as a standalone expression....

```
[InstanceName class];
```

... then the code is most likely forcing the execution of the `+initialize` method on  said class.    The first time any method is invoked on a class, the `+initialize` method will be invoked prior by the runtime.    So, have a look at `InstanceName` and see if it has a `+initialize` method.

Note that forcing `+initialize` to execute in this fashion is a sure sign of bad design.  `+initialize` should never need to be forced like this and should not have execution order dependencies.

---

There is a legitimate additional reason why this line of code might exist.  By referring to `InstanceName` with a hard reference, it'll force the linker to link in all symbols in the library.  (If you don't have a hard reference to at least one symbol in a library -- a .a -- some linkers will simply drop the library from the link unit entirely.)

Answer (score 2):

It gets the class of the object.

So for instance if InstanceName is an instance of class Foo

`[InstanceName class];` will return `Foo`, in a variable of type `Class`

You can use `class_getClassName` to get an `NSString` from this class to log it.

Comment: The runtime APIs never return an `NSString`.   `class` is a class method, not an instance method in the NSObject protocol, but an instance method does exist.

Answer (score 1):

`class` is a method inherited from [`NSObject`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/class). It lets you get the instance of the class object representing the class of the instance on which the method is called.

It can be used to examine the metadata of the current object. For example, you can use `class` method to determine if a given object is of a particular class:

```
if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I understand that in the context you provided, where you pass the result into some method. I couldn't get my head round seeing it as single line statement as [Foo class];

Comment: @lombausch Oh, I did not realize the expression is stand-alone.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the class of the object. Suppose you have an array of `UIView` subclasses you created and you want to perform some action only to those who belong to a certain class. You could loop through the array and check for each object's class:

```
for (id view in myViews) {
  if ([view isKindOfClass:[MyUIViewSubclass class]]) {
     // Do something
  }
}
```